# Multiple Sliders within Supersize plugin

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a question about the Supersize plugin (info about it can be found [here](http://buildinternet.com/2011/07/supersized-3-2-fullscreen-jquery-slideshow/) ). Here is my site so far: [hellothisis.cc](http://www.hellothisis.cc)

I have the slider and captions working just fine, but I'd like to have each caption be clickable to load another slider that contains images within just that project...I hope this makes sense.

For example, the first project says "Wood Slip Binding," I'd like to be able to click "Wood Slip Binding" and have the slider switch to a set of images of only that project, as opposed to cycling through different projects.

I imagine making the caption a link would be done with html in the slider script code? But is there a way to have multiple sliders within that page and have each caption call to a different slider? Or is it better to have the html link load a separate page with the specific slider?